# Ruby Single BackSlash Stored in Variable

Tags: ruby

\I have the following path: `E:\Path\Reports.`

If i want to store this path in a variable in ruby, i need to use "\\":

```
$location = "E:\\Path\\Reports"
```

Is there a way to avoid using the "\\" in the variable and still have the right path?

Comment: So you want to write a backslash without escaping it?

Comment: All what I want to do is be able to have something like this: $location = "E:\Path\Reports" and the value of the variable still be "E:\Path\Reports"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single-quoted strings interpret `\` as a literal character, rather than an escape character (except for `\'`, which is `'` literally):

```
$location = 'E:\Path\Reports'
```

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Single_quotes says otherwise.

Comment: Most cases you don't need to use the second escape sequence, unless it's at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

if you use this

```
location = 'E:\path\Reports'
```

it will be automatically escaped for you

Answer (score 1):

An easier way would be to use `File.join`. It'll use `/` but Ruby will take care of converting that to `\` under the hood on Windows.

```
$location = File.join('E', 'Path', 'Reports')
# $location is actually 'E/Path/Reports' now,
# but Ruby knows to convert the '/' to '\' on Windows.
```

This also has the benefit of making your code OS-independent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `%q`:

```
$location = %q{E:\Path\Reports}

=> $location
"E:\\Path\\Reports"

=> puts $location
E:\Path\Reports
```